# CSS styles does not get applied

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to apply a background color for the first row in the table. I gave that row a special class name. I also want to apply another color for the rest of the table's rows. The row colors do not get applied.

```css
.table {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
  border: 1;
}


/*I want the row with class head to be this color*/

.head {
  background-color: yellow;
}


/*I want the rest of the table rows this color*/

.table td {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="new-style.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body id="body">
  <table align='center' cellspacing=0 cellpadding=1 id="table" border=1 class="table">

    <tr id="head" class="head">
      <td class="head">Name</td>
      <td class="head">Type</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="initial-row">
      <td width=200> text here</td>
      <td width=200> text here </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="second-row">
      <td width=200> text here </td>
      <td width=200>text here </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use .head td {} instead

Comment: You mean the yellow is not applying?

Comment: add color to td instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're problem is with specificity and order - as you have put the light blue on the `td`, you need to override that with the yellow on the `td` too.

You then need to move the yellow declaration below the initial declaration as it is to the same specificity - this means order of the statements matter.

One final thing - remove `display:block` from the table, otherwise you will break the layout of the table.

```css
.table {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1;
  width:100%;
  /* remove display block from here otherwise your table layout will break */
}


/*put this first*/
.table td {
  background-color: lightblue;
}


/*override with this*/
.head td {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="new-style.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body id="body">
  <table align='center' cellspacing=0 cellpadding=1 id="table" border=1 class="table">

    <tr id="head" class="head">
      <td class="head">Name</td>
      <td class="head">Type</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="initial-row">
      <td width=200> text here</td>
      <td width=200> text here </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="second-row">
      <td width=200> text here </td>
      <td width=200>text here </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

[More information on css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Answer (score 1):

In addiction to [Pete's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44279156/1685157), I would like to say that if you want to create a table header to use the proper tag [`<th>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_th.asp)

```
<tr>
  <th class="head">Name</th>
  <th class="head">Type</th>
</tr>
```

> The `<th>` tag defines a header cell in an HTML table.
>
> An HTML table has two kinds of cells:
>
> - Header cells - contains header information (created with the  element)
> - Standard cells - contains data (created with the  element) The text in  elements are bold and centered by default.

```css
.table {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
  border: 1;
}


/*I want the row with class head to be this color*/

th {
  background-color: yellow;
}


/*I want the rest of the table rows this color*/

.table td {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="new-style.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body id="body">
  <table align='center' cellspacing=0 cellpadding=1 id="table" border=1 class="table">

    <tr id="head" class="head">
      <th class="head">Name</th>
      <th class="head">Type</th>
    </tr>

    <tr id="initial-row">
      <td width=200> text here</td>
      <td width=200> text here </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="second-row">
      <td width=200> text here </td>
      <td width=200>text here </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to increase the [*specificity*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of the CSS settings for `.head`

```css
.table {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
  border: 1;
}


/*I want the row with class head to be this color*/

.table .head {
  background-color: yellow;
}


/*I want the rest of the table rows this color*/

.table td {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="new-style.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body id="body">
<table align='center' cellspacing=0 cellpadding=1 id="table" border=1 class="table">

<tr id="head" class="head">
<td class="head">Name</td>
<td class="head">Type</td>
</tr>

<tr id="initial-row">
<td width=200> text here</td>
<td width=200 > text here </td>
</tr>

<tr id="second-row">
<td width=200 > text here </td>
<td width=200 >text here </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Btw, I just noticed that you use `table` as a class, maybe you should use another name ... more specific

Answer (score 0):

Remove the class `head` in the `tr` then add `!important`. For some reason the color is not changing without `!important` even if I re-arranged the css

```css
.table {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
  border: 1;
}


/*I want the row with class head to be this color*/

.head {
  background-color: yellow !important;
}


/*I want the rest of the table rows this color*/

.table td {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
  <table align='center' cellspacing=0 cellpadding=1 id="table" border=1 class="table">

    <tr id="head">
      <td class="head">Name</td>
      <td class="head">Type</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="initial-row">
      <td width=200> text here</td>
      <td width=200> text here </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="second-row">
      <td width=200> text here </td>
      <td width=200>text here </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: @PaoloForgia I know. I forgot to consider the specificity of `.head`, no wonder it is not applying

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr id="head" class="head">
    <th class="head">Name</td> <!-- change to th (table heading) -->
    <th class="head">Type</td>
</tr>
```

css:

```
th{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Pete mentioned, your specificity is incorrect. On a side note, your HTML markup could be improved to use the `<thead>` also and then your css could simply target `<th>` elements within the `<thead>`. This is better for accessibility as it clearly defines you "head" as a table header.

Take a look at the w3c docs on `<table>` markup for accessibilty @ https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/
or for general information about the markup check out the amazing Mozilla documentation @ https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

Something like this:

```css
.table {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
  border: 1;
}


/*I want the row with class head to be this color*/

thead th {
  background-color: yellow;
}


/*I want the rest of the table rows this color*/

tbody td {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="new-style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>

  <body id="body">
    <table align='center' cellspacing=0 cellpadding=1 id="table" border=1 class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr id="head">
          <th>Name</td>
          <th>Type</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="initial-row">
          <td>Text here</td>
          <td>Text here</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="second-row">
          <td>Text here</td>
          <td>Text here</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
/*I want the rest of the table rows this color*/

.table tr {
  background-color: lightblue;
}


/*I want the row with class head to be this color*/

.head {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

I think that should be codes above.